# Equivalent bash statment without closing parenthesis

Tags: bash, shell, vim, sh

I'm trying to replace an editor command like "vim" with an equivalent command that strips color codes from the input file before invoking the editor command. The script is to be invoked by bash and must fit in the format `command + ' ' + filename` so the trailing `)` is giving me trouble:

```
EDITOR <(sed -e "s/\x1B\[[0-9;]*[JKmsu]//g" < color.js)
```

Can you think of a way to do this without the trailing `)`, everything must come before the file name?

Comment: I don't understand the "why"? I assume that the "command + filename" constraint implies no spaces in the filename -- what causes that constraint? It feels like there are several important details you've omitted.

Comment: The constraint comes from this being a shim that will be injected inside of compiled code that I cannot change not from spaces in the file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your current command works, simply rewrite it as a function:

```
edit() { $EDITOR <(sed -e "s/\x1B\[[0-9;]*[JKmsu]//g" < "$1"); }; edit
```

However, the better approach is to create a script that does what you want to do and invoke that. This allows other programs to invoke the editor without passing it through a shell, which not all of them do.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
bash -c 'EDITOR <(sed -e "s/\x1B\[[0-9;]*[JKmsu]//g" < "$0")' color.js
\.........................................................../ \....../
                   command                                    filename
```